# If $X$ is a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$ how is $X^2$ distributed?

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X$ is a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$ how is $X^2$ distributed?
Any explanation would be very appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to work this out yourself (Hint: $P\{X^2 = k\} = 0$ unless $k$ is the square of a non-negative integer). As far as I know, there is no specific name for this distribution: call it Squared-Poisson if you like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your title would be better phrased as "If $X$ is a Poisson-distributed random variable with mean $\lambda$, how is $X^2$ distributed?" or "If $X$ *has* a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$, how is $X^2$ distributed?".

I don't think much can be said beyond the fact that $\Pr(X^2 = x^2) = \dfrac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$.

One thing of possible interest is that $\operatorname{E}(X^2) = \lambda+\lambda^2.\,$  This is an instance of a pattern:
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}(X^3) & = \lambda + 3\lambda^2 + \lambda^3 \\
\operatorname{E}(X^4) & = \lambda + 7\lambda^2 + 6 \lambda^3 + \lambda^4 \\
\operatorname{E}(X^5) & = \lambda + 15\lambda^2 + 25 \lambda^3 + 10\lambda^4 + \lambda^5 \\
& \,\,\, \vdots
\end{align}
$$
The coefficient of $\lambda^k$ in the expansion of $\operatorname{E}(X^n)$ is the number of (**un**-ordered) partitions of a set of size $n$ into $k$ parts.  I.e., it's $\left\{\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right\} = {}$a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number_of_the_second_kind).  These are called the "exponential polynomials" or ["Touchard polynomials"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials).

Comment: Thank you very much! Could to elaborate how you found the expectation of $X^2$?

Comment: @LHS: I think the easiest way to find $E(X^2)$ is to first find $E(X(X-1))$.

Comment: @LHS : I think the comment by André Nicolas is what you need.  It's easier to find the "factorial moments" $\mathbb{E}(X(X-1)(X-2)\cdots(X-n+1))$ than the moments $\mathbb{E}(X^n)$.  But if you know the first $n$ factorial moments, you can use them to find the first $n$ moments.  That doesn't prove that the assertion about partitions above will continue to hold for all $n$.  For that, you might start with the article on Stirling numbers.

Comment: Thank you both very much! this is very helpful